# ORA-00917: missing comma - Insert query failed

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I'm trying to create insert query in JSP page as follows

```
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try 
    {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:" + "XE", "hr","hr");

        if (connection != null) 
        {
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            String q2 = "INSERT INTO HR.tweets (";
            q2 = q2 + "DATE_TIME,USER_NAME,TWEET_BEFORE,TWEET_AFTER)";
            q2 = q2 + "VALUES (";
            q2 = q2 + "(select SYSDATE from dual),";
            q2 = q2 + "'" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + "'" + ",";
            q2 = q2 + "'" + tweet.getText() + "'" +",";
            q2 = q2 + "'" + finalstring + "')";

            statement.execute(q2);   
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

At `statement.execute(q2)` I'm getting `ORA-00917: missing comma error`.

The following query is created in a code :

```
INSERT INTO HR.tweets (DATE_TIME,USER_NAME,TWEET_BEFORE,TWEET_AFTER)VALUES ((select SYSDATE from dual),'Dannazxcv','RT @HugotInhinyero: Wish we could turn back time to the good old days. When our mama sings us to sleep but now we're stressed out.
#engin…','hugotinhinyero turn back time good days. mama sing sleep we're stress out.   engin'  )
```

Please help me.

Comment: The following query is created in a code : INSERT INTO HR.tweets (DATE_TIME,USER_NAME,TWEET_BEFORE,TWEET_AFTER)VALUES ((select SYSDATE from dual),'Dannazxcv','RT @HugotInhinyero: Wish we could turn back time to the good old days. When our mama sings us to sleep but now we're stressed out.
engin…','hugotinhinyero turn back time good days. mama sing sleep we're stress out. engin' )

Comment: Change those 2 lines to   `q2 = q2 + "SELECT";
            q2 = q2 + "SYSDATE,";` and add a FROM DUAL parameter at the end

Comment: No need for the `select` in the first place. Just use `sysdate` in the values clause. But you should ***really*** be using a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL insert has an syntax error since one of your parameters contains a `'`:

```
'hugotinhinyero turn back time good days. mama sing sleep we're stress out. engin'
```

To avoid this kind of errors, don't build SQL strings manually, but use a `PreparedStatement` and parameters instead:

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO HR.tweets (DATE_TIME,USER_NAME,TWEET_BEFORE,TWEET_AFTER) " + 
" VALUES ((select SYSDATE from dual),?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(insert);
stmt.setParameter(1, tweet.getUser().getScreenName());
stmt.setParameter(2, tweet.getText());
stmt.setParameter(3, finalstring);
stmt.executUpdate();
```

Comment: No need for the `select`. `VALUES (SYSDATE,?,?,?)` will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using special characters, which causes the statement sent through to the database to be invalid.

Try using a prepared statement like this...

```
PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
Connection connection = null;
    try 
    {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:" + "XE", "hr","hr");

        if (connection != null) 
        {
            pstatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO HR.tweets (DATE_TIME,USER_NAME,TWEET_BEFORE,TWEET_AFTER) VALUES ((select SYSDATE from dual),?,?,?)");


            q2 = q2 + "'" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + "'" + ",";
            q2 = q2 + "'" + tweet.getText() + "'" +",";
            q2 = q2 + "'" + finalstring + "')";
            pstatement.setString(1, tweet.getUser().getScreenName());
            pstatement.setString(2,tweet.getText());
            pstatement.setString(3, finalstring);
            pstatement.execute();   

        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        pstatement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
```

...prepared statements usually take care of malformed strings and invalid quotes sent to the DB.

Comment: No need for the `select sysdate`. `VALUES (SYSDATE,?,?,?)` will do just fine. Plus you are missing the closing `)` for the `values` clause

Comment: Thanks for the correction Yep the statement is missing ")"

Comment: Fixed the missing bracket, once again thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`.
Your query will always fail if any of your field will contain quote character (`'`).
Besides, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, while PreparedStatement guards against a such attack.

Details on PreparedStatement can be found in this tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
This is a very very basic knowledge so I dont't explain it here.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers. My Problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @wero, the issue with the query is that it contains a quote ('). To escape it you can use a [backslash](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm) (\).

```
Eg: we\'re
```

However like other's have suggested, its safer to use [prepared-statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) which also take care of guarding against sql-injection as a bonus !